# Find all rows that rank within top 50 in column1 AND in column2 AND in column3

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table of characters like this:
(I use game stats only because it's easier to understand)

```
id    age  strength intelligence speed
 1    int    int       int        int
 2    int    int       int        int
 3    int    int       int        int
 4    int    int       int        int
 5    int    int       int        int
 6    int    int       int        int
 7    int    int       int        int
...   ...    ...       ...        ...
999   int    int       int        int
```

How can I write a MySQL query to find all characters under 30 years old that are ranked top 50 in strength AND top 50 in intelligence AND top 50 in speed?

The tricky part is that this query will not be hard-coded, it'll be constructed by code from the front end, and all the criterias are dynamic, so I wanted to have a query that's flat and scalable, better without many nested JOINS where the x.id = y.id = z.id part changes in every JOIN, which is hard to code.

I've spent many hours reading docs but couldn't do it elegantly. I tried WHERE id IN, but MySQL doesn't support it in this case. I also read about EXISTS, but docs says its performance is really bad.

Comment: what is your version of mysql?

Comment: I use MySQL Workbench 6.3 to test. Why?

Comment: please share your efforts !

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a tool to connect to MySQL. Its version is not MySQL’s version.

Comment: I'd be tempted to revise my data model. What if you decide to include dexterity ? Are you going to add another column? That's bonkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spencer7593's answer is good, but since you want "flat and scalable" and you only have 1 table, use USING() instead of ON is a good idea:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY strength DESC LIMIT 50)
t1
JOIN (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY intelligence DESC LIMIT 50)
t2 USING (id)
JOIN (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY speed DESC LIMIT 50)
t3 USING (id)
JOIN mytable USING (id)
WHERE age < 30;
```

This way it becomes easy to code the request from your front end into query

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The specification doesn't make clear what is meant by "ranked top 50".

Assuming that means getting the first 50 rows of all rows, as ordered by `strength`, and discarding/excluding the remaining rows...

I'd suggest using a series of inline views to get fifty id values each, and join those sets to get the intersection ...

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.age
      , t.strength
      , t.intelligence
      , t.strength
   FROM ( SELECT qq.id 
            FROM mytable qq
           ORDER BY qq.strength DESC 
           LIMIT 50
        ) q
   JOIN ( SELECT rr.id 
            FROM mytable rr
           ORDER BY rr.intelligence DESC 
           LIMIT 50
        ) r
     ON r.id = q.id
   JOIN ( SELECT ss.id 
            FROM mytable ss
           ORDER BY ss.speed DESC 
           LIMIT 50
        ) s
     ON s.id = q.id 
   JOIN mytable t
     ON t.id = q.id
  WHERE t.age < 30   
  ORDER BY ...
```

For best performance, we want appropriate indexes, to avoid expensive "Using filesort" operations, e.g.

```
... ON mytable (strength, ...)
... ON mytable (intelligence, ...)      
... ON mytable (speed, ...)
```

Assuming there's a suitable index with `id` as the leading column e.g. if InnoDB, `id` column is the PRIMARY KEY (cluster index).  Use `EXPLAIN` to see execution plan.

Comment: Hi @spencer7593, thanks for your answer! You obviously are very good, and many things you mentioned I didn't understand (like using filesort), but after some trials I put together a solution and submitted my own answer, which seems shorter. Please take a look and if you think it's correct, I'll select my own as the right answer. Thanks!